# Unwanted pop-up in Microsoft Teams bot

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I created a bot using the Microsoft Teams Bot Framework v4.
I installed the bot, but every time I switched to the bot conversation I have the pop-up like in the image below.[image]

It sits above the input text field, it states "What can I do?" and clicking on it just toggles between up and down arrow at the end of the row.

How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 2):

[Bot menu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-menus) aid discovery and to help educate users about your bot’s functionality. These are set in your app manifest file. You can remove **commandLists** from your bots section if you want to get rid of it.

Comment: Omitting or removing commandLists doesn't prevent it from appearing, I'm afraid. Perhaps it should, but that's not what it does today.

Comment: The response says that it's enough to remove commandLists from the bot section.

Comment: @BillBliss-MSFT please post a complete answer and I'll vote it.